# Basic auth with Guzzle showing 401 in Postman

Tags: php, guzzle

I'm posting to a valid endpoint with valid JSON. The problem seems to be around authorisation. If I dump the JSON from my web app and insert that directly into my API, I get the result I'm expecting. If I take that same JSON and, through Postman, post to my API by selecting Basic Authorisation in the Authorisation tab and adding my API token (no password required it seems), I also get the result I expect.

However, when posting via my web app, I'm using Guzzle to send the request, and I actually get a 200 response from the API except it doesn't do what's expected. The response is incomplete. I'm using the following in my web app to do basic auth via Guzzle:

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client([
    'http_errors' => $this->errors,
    'base_uri' => $this->base_uri,
    'verify' => false
]);
        
if(isset($this->token['token'])) {
    $auth = [
        'auth' => [
            $this->token['token'],
            $this->password
        ]
    ];
}
       
$headers = [
    'headers' => [
        'Accept' => 'application/json'
    ]
];

$body = array_merge($auth, $headers, $body);
$response = $client->request($method, $uri, $body);
$data = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents());

return $data;
```

So, I should be able to do a dump of `$body` which gives me the following request data:

```json
{
    "auth": [
        "token",
        "pass"
    ],
    "headers": {
        "Accept": "application\/json"
    },
    "Orders": [
        {
            valid json
        }
    ]
}
```

In theory, I should be able to post this via Postman in raw and get the desired result, instead I get 401 Authorisation Missing, whereas I'm specifically posting the auth data in raw as per Guzzle would.

The response from the API is unusual also as it suggests it's a success. It would appear, that even though I'm passing the basic auth data through Guzzle as per the docs, it doesn't pass through?

To summarise, I've tried posting via the app's UI (swagger) with my JSON (valid). This works. I've then tried sending that JSON via Postman, specifically using my API token in the Basic Authorisation tab of Postman, this also works. Therefore, I know my JSON is valid. However, when trying the same thing from my web app it fails. The response from the API is Success, so as far as the web app is concerned all is well. I've then dumped the data (as above) from my web app to show the request in full, with the auth and headers, and this DOES NOT subsequently work in Postman.

Comment: Try adding `'Authorization' => 'Basic ' . base64_encode($this->token['token'] . ':' . $this->password)` to your headers. You shouldn't need a auth array key and need not pass it the body.

Comment: So from Postman you are sending the auth using `electing Basic Authorisation in the Authorisation tab and adding my API token` right which mean it's going via headers but then through your web app also you should send it via headers and not body.